# jquery applying css tag

Tags: jquery, css

```
$($("#myDiv")).append("<b>Hello</b>");
```

how can i apply to mydiv display:none

Comment: err... `$("#myDiv").hide();`? That question has two tiny sentences and a title, all almost non-related. You may want to elaborate a bit.

Comment: use `$("#myDiv").hide()` or `$("#myDiv").css('display','none');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't manipulate the `display` CSS property with `css()`. Use `hide()`:

```
$("#myDiv").hide().append("Hello");
```

Why are you doing:

```
$($("#myDiv"))...
```

?

Comment: it will also compressed the place it is using?

Comment: @mazhar what do you mean by "compressed"?

Answer (score 2):

$("#myDiv").css("display","none");  should do the trick but look into the jquery hide method too [(hide)](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) which can hide the div "smoothly" if you want that.